# Return Data Frame values with list of indices

Tags: r

Is there a way to return values of a dataframe based on a list of indices with R? For example

```
a b c d
1 1 1 1 
2 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3 
4 4 4 4
```

with a list of indices to return:

```
[0,2]
```

will return

```
a b c d
1 1 1 1 
3 3 3 3
```

Comment: @RichardScriven I believe the OP is literally just asking how to do row indexing of data frames, in this case looking for the 1st and 3rd rows.

Comment: Haha, I even wrote the answer wrong.  I think you are right Joran

Comment: In R, indices start at 1. Not at 0. And if you ask this kind of questions, you might benefit from googling yourself a tutorial on R-dataframes and how to handle them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not fully sure whether that is what you are looking for but you could do the following:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:4, b=1:4)
```

Then the command

```
df[c(1,3),]
```

gives you

```
  a b
1 1 1
3 3 3
```

To explain a bit more: `[0,2]` does not work (looks pythonic), but you need to use `c(1,3)` which creates a vector with the numbers 1 and 3. In R, indices start at 1 and not 0. Then you can pass this vector as an argument to your data frame and leave the column unspecified; therefore, all of them get returned. If you want to get only the 1st column returned you could do:

```
df[c(1,3),1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course there is. Just use the [subsetting/extraction operator, `[`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html), which has the general format

```
df[rows, columns]
```

… and provide a vector of row indices. Leave the column index argument empty to get all columns:

```
df[c(1, 3), ]
```

Note that indices in R start at 1, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data frame is:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:4, b = 1:4, c = 1:4, d = 1:4)
```

And your indices are:

```
id <- c(1,3)
```

You can just do:

```
df[id,]
```

Not specifying a column after the comma returns them all